# Python CSV skip or delete 2nd row

Tags: python, string, csv

All,

This is a snippet of a text file that I need to change into a csv file.

```
|head1|head2|head3|
+----+------+-----+
|10000|10001|10002|
```

So I've used this python code to make it into a CSV.

```
#open the input & output files.
inputfile = open('tr2796h_05.10.txt', 'rb')
csv_file = r"mycsv1.csv"
out_csvfile = open(csv_file, 'wb')

#read in the correct lines
my_text = inputfile.readlines()[63:-8]
#convert to csv using | as delimiter
in_txt = csv.reader(my_text, delimiter = '|')
#hook csv writer to output file
out_csv = csv.writer(out_csvfile)
#write the data
out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
#close up
inputfile.close()
out_csvfile.close()
```

The output is this:

```
,head1,head2,head3,
,+----+------+-----+,
,10000,10001,10002,
```

as expected.

**Question is this - how do I delete that second row?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the headers, skip a row, and then write the remaining rows.

```
out_csv.writerow(next(in_txt)) # headers
next(in_text) # skip
out_csv.writerows(in_txt) # write remaining
```

Comment: I believe you transcribed my first line incorrectly.  Note that it is `writerow` not `writerows`.

Comment: You were spot on.

Is this or Lonut Hulub's method below the 'preferred' way of doing things?
Could you help me understand the benefits of either?

Comment: @TangoAlee.  Ionut Hulub's answer is spot on for your situation.  My answer will work even in situations where you don't prefetch the data.

Comment: I want to accept both answers but can't apparently. I've accepted yours!

Answer (score 1):

Add `del my_text[1]` after `my_text = inputfile.readlines()[63:-8]`.